# Is the "ll" in Albanian like the sounds in other languages?

Tags: phonology, cross-linguistic, albanian, laterals

Albanian has a digraph letter "ll" which is described as being similar to English "dark l".

But how similar is it and how different? My native Australian English has dark l and to me it tends to turn into a "w" or "u" sound at the end of words and I'm not sure it's the same, maybe it varies a lot.

Then there are some more or less exotic sounds I know of but imperfectly in other languages, some which are also spelled with a version of "l" or "ll".

Polish also has a "w-ish l" that is spelled with the letter "ł". But my hunch is that this one maybe used to be a kind of "l" but is now firmly a "w".

I also speak Spanish but learned in Mexico where "ll" mostly sounds the same as "y" so that's also difficult to compare.

Welsh also has a special letter they spelled with an "ll" digraph. It's said to be unique though and the way I produce it is very raspy so it would seem the least likely to be similar. But maybe I'm not doing it right since most Welsh people I meet can't speak Welsh anyway and are probably just humouring me.

So which if any of these is Albanian "ll" most like?

Comment: Isn't this way too localized for this site?

Comment: @Louis: It's hard to say what's too localized, especially for a new site. Stack Exchange specifically aims for long-tail questions. Sometimes I put too much in my questions which can make them seem really specific but I could've asked in a more simplistic way "What is the Albanian 'll' sound like in other languages?" But since I know some linguatrivia I have a habit of including it my questions.

Comment: @Louis: I'll try to reword the question so that I'm asking more generally but still include the stuff I'm partly familiar with.

Comment: @Louis, I fail to see how a question referring to so many unconnected languages and comparing so many different ways of pronouncing the *ll* digraph can be deemed "too localised". hippietrail, your Australian "dark l" is probably the closest to the Albanian *ll*. Especially considering that the Australian "dark l" also occurs *within* words (i.e. not just in final position), just as in Albanian or Catalan. If you meet some native speaker, you can ask him to pronounce this proverb: "Në prill, mbill" (in April, sow). I don't think the Welsh *ll* is velarised. Mexican Sp. /ʎ/, Argentina Sp. /ʃ/.

Comment: Oh I thought about including something in my question saying I realized it looks like I'm asking about the digraph but I'm really asking about the sounds which coincidentally seem to often be written with the same digraph. It's probably partly related I guess. I'm always aware my questions tend to be too long as it is but maybe I leave the wrong things out (-: Oh in my experience /ʎ/ is not common in Mexico, I mostly heard /j/ but some few speakers use /ʒ/ like Argentines, which I wouldn't describe as /ʃ/.

Comment: @hippietrail. The variations of the pronunciation of the *ll* digraph in the various dialects of Spanish is probably worth a question of its own, and is actually [already looming on the horizon](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage) ;-). As for now, you might want to refer to the [rioplatense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rioplatense_Spanish#Phonology) WP article. Y también darle una mirada a [este artículo en lengua española](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll) ;-).

Comment: It sounds like you speak a variety of English that has [L-vocalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_vocalization). If that's the case, then you might indeed have a [w]-ish sound instead of [ɫ] in words like "ball".

Comment: @Dan - I'm actually not sure what I have. It's hard to be your own linguistic informant. Definitely when I'm at home some people around me have l-vocalization and I think all or some have dark-l but I have no feeling for it at all. Also I've lost my natural accent due to years of travelling or being surround by foreign tourists and it only really comes back when I spend time with my family, currently on the other side of the world to me. So I don't really know how to test. Maybe that's a good question of it's own then...

Comment: FYI, Welsh "ll" is a lateral fricative, not a liquid.  Pretty sure its realized as /ɬ/.

Comment: @AdeleC you're right, the sound is also present in the Uto-Aztecan language Nahuatl (including in the name of language itself - /Na:watɬ/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_L), it's similar to the English dark L (as "ll" in *ba**ll***).

To be precise, we are talking about a *[velarized alveolar lateral approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant)* (an audio file is available); its IPA symbol is `ɫ`.

The Albanian word "**halla**" (*aunt*), for example, is transcribed as `[ˈhaɫa]`.

---

Regarding the **Polish** one, it has a "w" sound, such as in **mały** (*small*) and **łaska** (*grace*) in the [Consonants section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_phonology#Consonants), see the table called "Example words".

Comment: The same Wikipedia article notes that some Eastern dialects of Polish still use the sound [ł] for ł (where standard Polish uses [w]): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_phonology#Dialectal_variation_of_consonants

Answer (score 2):

That would be incorrect, as an albanian speaker surrounded by Albanian speakers, I can testify that 'll' is actually an interdental lateral consonant.

Comment: ***That's*** an interesting description. I've never heard of an interdental lateral before; but it's certainly possible, and flattening the blade of the tongue laterally against the dorsum does produce velarization as well. But  it's not necessarily rounded, like the tendency with English postvocalic (dark) /l/ to decay to a /w/, especially word-finally. Is it rounded in your speech community?

Comment: In Albanian it's not rounded, but I did remember it is also still velarized. Though, when Albanian pronunciation is taught to students, there's no mention of velarization, as that seems to be the most natural consequence of any interdental consonant in my opinion.