# How can I write an interdental lateral in phonetic transcription?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, phonemes, phonetic-symbols, laterals

Inspired by [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/449/is-the-ll-in-albanian-like-the-sounds-in-other-languages/13092#13092) here is my question: How can I write a *interdental lateral* in phonetic transcription (IPA preferred, but not a necessary requirement, other wide spread phonetic notation systems are also welcome)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[extIPA](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/sites/default/files/extIPA_2016.pdf) gives you these options:

- Voiceless interdental lateral fricative: ɬ̪͆
- Voiced interdental lateral fricative: ɮ̪͆
- Voiced interdental lateral approximant: l̪͆

However, I find these diacritics a bit of overkill, especially given American English /θ, ð/ are also usually interdental but never transcribed with these diacritics anyway. I bet just [ɬ̪, ɮ̪, l̪] (or even [ɬ, ɮ, l], unless the language contrasts interdental with (post)alveolar) would suffice in most occasions.

Answer (score 0):

With a different idea, interpreting the interdental lateral as a lateralized th sound and using the IPA character ˡ (raised l) for lateral release: /ðˡˤ/. This sound is attested according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_consonant#Lateralized_consonants) for some Modern South Arabic language or some Southern Arabic dialect.

Comment: I'm not sure if a fricative can be "released", which is a concept usually only applied to occlusives. But I guess one could argue that rather justifies the use of <ˡ> along with a fricative symbol to signify lateral rather than lateral release.